# Whether to transform non-normal pre-test when running linear regression on transformed post-test?

Tags: regression, data-transformation, normality-assumption

I'm running linear regression model on a post-intervention test score controlling for pre-intervention test score. I used Box-Cox transformation on the post-intervention test score to normalize it. Since there no normality assumption imposed on independent variable, I plan not to transform the pre-intervention test score; but since the pre- and post-test are on a same scale, should I transform the pre-test as well just to be consistent?

Comment: Bear in mind that inferences on transform data cannot be validly applied to non-transformed data because $f(\sigma^{2}_{X}) \ne \sigma^{2}_{f(X)}$. So if you find statistical evidence that $f(X) \ne f(Y)$ you **did not** just find statistical evidence that $X \ne Y$.

Comment: A similar question with answer [Skewness transformation for one but not the other variable?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/243975/skewness-transformation-for-one-but-not-the-other-variable/243984#243984)

Answer (score 2):

I'd say yes, you should use the same transformation on both -- largely for a non-technical reason: You're going to have to explain your analysis to somebody. Since the pre- and post-scores are on the same scale, it's just kinda weird not to keep them on the same scale.