# Skewness transformation for one but not the other variable?

Tags: anova, modeling, data-transformation, skewness, intuition

I have two dependent variables, one is positively skewed (significantly), the other is negatively skewed (not significant). I can apply a log10 transformation to improve the skewness on the first one.

Questions:

1. Can I then statistically compare the two variables in a mixed ANOVA test (the two variables are steps of a factor "emotion" and I compare between factor "group"), given that one is transformed and the other isn't?
2. If not, what options do I have?

Comment: First, is this an independent samples comparison or a paired comparison?              I Guess the first, but that information should be in your post!

Comment: Sorry about that! I was trying to keep it simple, but I should have realised that that may be essential information. Have updated the text now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is an independent samples comparison, and that you want to compare the expectation of the two groups the samples are drawn from.  If it is a paired sample, the distribution of the two groups separately is irrelevant, what is relevant is the distribution of the difference.

Let us write a model.
$$ \DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb{E}}
Y_{11},\dots,Y_{1n} \sim \text{iid with mean $\mu_1$, variance $\sigma^2$} \\
Y_{21},\dots,Y_{2m} \sim \text{iid with mean $\mu_2$, variance $\sigma^2$}
$$
Now, if you use some transform (logarithm, whatever, say $g$) of, say , $Y_2$, then you can bet that $\E g(Y_2) \not = \mu_2$, so that, even if 
the null hypothesis is true, that is, $\mu_1=\mu_2$, the corresponding null hypothesis after the transformation will **not** be true, so the results of the t-test applied after transforming only one group will be meaningless (it will test another null than what you want). That answer your point 1.

For the second point, multiple options:

1. Find a compromise transformation for both groups
2. Use the t-test with bootstrapping
3. Use some nonparametric test
4. Use a permutation test
5. Probably other ideas.

For choosing between these ideas, we would need to know about your context.

Comment: Tahnks @kjetil! If I understand your first point correctly, you are saying that transforming one and not the other is meaningless and should not be done. From the 2nd point I gather a compromise transformation would be a good idea (boostrapping for ANOVA in SPSS is not easy/an actual option, I know of no nonparametric tests equivalent for  a mixed repeated measures ANOVA and I don't know what a permutation test ist :)

Comment: If you found this answer helpful youcan upvote and accept it. If it was not useful, please explain why you still have a problem.